# fail2ban.filter : ERROR No 'host' found in

Tags: fail2ban

I am trying to block scripts that are scanning my sites for admin-pages by using fail2ban with my nginx-logs. But I am receiving errors looking like this in my fail2ban-log(with different requests/useragents/remote_addresses):

```
2015-09-18 14:45:42,137 fail2ban.filter : ERROR  No 'host' found in ' +0200 - ***.**.***.*** http://www.example.com - - "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 404 737 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/44.0.2403.89 Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36"' using '<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0xc53590>'
```

My fail2ban-regex looks like this:

```
failregex = \+0200 - <HOST> https?://.*[Aa]dmin.* ((301)|(404))
```

my nginx-logformat looks like this:

```
log_format vhosts '$time_local - $remote_addr $scheme://$host - $remote_user "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

when I run fail2ban-regex with that log-line I get:

```
fail2ban-regex '18/Sep/2015:14:45:42 +0200 - ***.**.***.*** http://www.example.com - - "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 404 737 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/44.0.2403.89 Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36"' '\+0200 - <HOST> https?://.*[Aa]dmin.* ((301)|(404))'

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : \+0200 - <HOST> https?://.*[Aa]dmin.* ((301)|(404))
Use      single line : 18/Sep/2015:14:45:42 +0200 - ***.**.***.*** http:/...


Results
=======

Failregex: 1 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1] \+0200 - <HOST> https?://.*[Aa]dmin.* ((301)|(404))
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1] Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed
```

The IP is replaced with ***.***.**.*** . The host-adress with www.example.com. In the fail2ban-regex I used the real ip and host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly remember how I resolved this problem, but my currently working failregex looks like this:

```
failregex = ^.*?<HOST> https?://.*?[Aa]dmin.*? ((301)|(404)).*$
```

I guess the fix was eighter `.*?` instead of `\+0200 -` or the `^` at the beginning and the `$` at the end.